# I can't understand what's going wrong with my code in python. (I tried to combine the 'turtle' and 'keyboard' libraries)

Tags: python, python-turtle, python-keyboard

I'm a beginner in programming and have encountered an issue with my code. I even tried to use AI, but it's code didn't work at all. Here is my code:

```
from keyboard import is_pressed as isp
import keyboard
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(10)
r_ang = 10

is_writing=True

def is_wr(is_writing):
    is_writing = not is_writing

def on_f_key_event(e):
    if e.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        is_wr(is_writing)
keyboard.hook_key('f', on_f_key_event)



while True:
    if isp('w'):
        t.forward(2)
    if isp('a'):
        t.left(r_ang)
    if isp('d'):
        t.right(r_ang)
    if is_writing:
        t.pendown()
    if is_writing==False:
        t.penup()
```

The program should allow you to control the drawing turtle with the wad keys and switch writing mode to the f key. Drawing already works, but switching the writing mode doesn't. Every time I try to fix something, the program either fails to perform the action or gives a lot of errors that I don't understand. My problem is that I can't register the f key press to enable and disable drawing for the turtle. *This version of the code does not generate errors, but it does not perform the function either.
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: `is_wr()` has no effect other than changing a local variable, when then vanishes at the completion of the function.  The global `is_writing` variable is not affected.

Comment: If you assign a value to a variable anywhere in a function, the variable is seen as local and shadows other variables of the same name. In `is_wr` you create a local `is_writing` variable. Declare it using the `global` declaration to access the global variable instead.